Adyen javascript call function after component mount
We have an application that uses Adyen as PSP. To start payments, we mount the components for the payment methods using javascript with checkout.create('directEbanking').mount('#sofort-container') for example. When the components (in our case for directEbanking and bcmc_mobile) have been mounted, I want to call a different function. I want to slightly modify the mounted Adyen component when it has been rendered, but searching the event directly after calling the mount function gives no result, because the components have not been rendered yet.
I can't seem to find a solution for something like onMount configuration where I can feed a function that will be called when a component has been mounted and rendered. Any ideas?

What are you trying to modify/customise?

The Adyen components will create buttons to initiate payments. As soon as they have been rendered, I want to add a specific class name to it, based on the background color of the button. I can only add the class name when the button has been rendered.

The Adyen Drop-in or components do not support this customisation on-the-fly. You typically have 2 options to customise the styling.
If you need to customise the appearance dynamically, you can observe the DOM changes, waiting for the elements to be generated and rendered.
One approach is to use the MutationObserver API to watch for changes in the DOM:
  const dropin = checkout.create(type);
  const paymentContainer = document.getElementById("payment");

  const observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutationsList, observer) {
    // Check for the presence of the Pay button
    const elem = document.querySelector('.adyen-checkout__button');
    if (elem) {
      elem.classList.add("my-custom-button");
      observer.disconnect();
    } else {
      console.log("Button not found yet");
    }
  });

  // Start observing mutations
  observer.observe(paymentContainer, { childList: true, subtree: true });

  // Mount the Drop-in component
  dropin.mount(paymentContainer);

